# arrow passing through/over bracket?

Tags: symbols, arrows

In LaTeX, how can I output an arrow passing through/over a bracket?

[image: What I want to get]

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SX!](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436) Your post was migrated here from [so]. Please register on this site, too, and make sure that both accounts are associated with each other (by using the same OpenID), otherwise you won't be able to comment on or accept answers or edit your question.

Answer (score 5):

Here are two options:

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{mathtools}

\newcommand{\lbarrow}{\mathrel{{\ooalign{$\rightarrow$\cr\hidewidth$($\hidewidth}}}}
\newcommand{\rbarrow}{\mathrel{{\ooalign{$\rightarrow$\cr\hidewidth$)$\hidewidth}}}}

\makeatletter
\newcommand{\lrparen}[1]{%
  \settowidth{\@tempdima}{#1}%
  \kern.5\@tempdima\mathclap{(#1)}\kern.5\@tempdima}
\makeatother

\begin{document}

It is clear that $x \lbarrow y \rbarrow z$ and so forth.

It is clear that $x \rightarrow \lrparen{y} \rightarrow z$ and so forth.

\end{document}
```

Comment: Wouldn't `\newcommand{\lrparen}[1]{\mathrel{\!(#1)\!}}` be simpler?

Answer (score 1):

Here I `\stackinset` a paren within the horizontal extent of the `\rightarrow`.  The horizontal placement of the paren is controlled by the 2nd parameter to `\stackinset`.  By using the `{c}` anchors, the horizontal (2nd argument) and vertical (4th argument) offsets are taken relative to the center of the `\rightarrow`.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{mathtools,stackengine}
\stackMath
\newcommand{\lbarrow}{\stackinset{c}{-1pt}{c}{}{(}{\rightarrow}}
\newcommand{\rbarrow}{\stackinset{c}{-1.5pt}{c}{}{)}{\rightarrow}}
\begin{document}
It is clear that $x \lbarrow y \rbarrow z$ and so forth.
\end{document}
```

[image]